# Does the WebBrowser control in .NET store the previous navigated page?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

Does the WebBrowser control in the .NET Framework store the previous navigated page in memory? If it stores the page, I want to delete these pages from memory. How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Someone else was editing at the same time I was; if I overwrote their changes I apologize. Please feel free to re-edit or rollback.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Travel Log object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768366%28VS.85%29.aspx). To get access to it, you need to get the native IWebBrowser2 interface of the browser, QI for IServiceProvider, QueryService for SID_STravelLogCursor for ITravelLogStg, [enumerate the entries to find the one you want to delete](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/ITravelLogStg.html) and call ITravelLogStg.RemoveEntry.

Answer (score 0):

```
webBrowser1.GoBack();

webBrowser1.Refresh();
```